# How to add Recent queries to another activity

Tags: java, android

I am creating searchable dictionary and I want to display the most recent queries that user does in SearchView to other activity. just Like Recent option in android dictionaries.

```
private void handleIntent(Intent inent) {
 if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // handles a click on a search suggestion; launches activity to show word
        Intent wordIntent = new Intent(this, WordActivity.class);
        wordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
        startActivity(wordIntent);
        finish();
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // handles a search query
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions=new SearchRecentSuggestions(this, MySuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY, MySuggestionProvider.MODE);
        suggestions.saveRecentQuery(query, null);
        showResults(query);
    }
}
```

The ShowResult shows the query suggestions in the search activity, i want to show the recent queries into an other activity, how can i do this?

Comment: i think , by creating another table in database or using shared preference , you can store those suggestion in table or shared preference .

Answer (score 0):

May be this code will help you with Shared Preference .

```
SharedPreferences sPreferences = getSharedPreferences("tushar", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor sEditor = sPreferences.edit();

Set<String> setName = new HashSet<String>();
setName.add("tushar");
setName.add("pandey");
setName.add("Ram");
setName.add("Shiva");

sEditor.putStringSet("ko", setName);
sEditor.commit() ;

Log.i("hello","tushar:pandey") ;
Set<String> setName_ = sPreferences.getStringSet("tushar", setName);
Log.i(setName_.toString(),"tushar:pandey") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is possible to access saved queries through ContentResolver:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();

String contentUri = "content://" + MySuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY + '/' + SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY;

Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriStr);

Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, new String[] { null }, null);
```

Now with received cursor populate a ListView. Create another activity using showResults() code.